# Can't Save to an XML file in an embedded resource

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, embedded-resource

I am testing an app to read from a XML file (Working) and save to a XML file (NOT WORKING).

Here is my code that is not working. any ideas on how to fix this? I need to be able to save to the XML file. The error I am getting is: STREAM WAS NOT WRITEABLE

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strTime As String
    strTime = Now.ToString
    Dim _assembly As Assembly
    _assembly = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()
    Dim FileName = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("EmbeddedResource.xml")

    Try
        Dim xmlData As New XmlDocument
        Dim nodeRoot, nodeTroubleInfo, nodeDateTimeSaved As XmlNode
        xmlData.Load(FileName)
        nodeRoot = xmlData.SelectSingleNode("//DATA")
        nodeTroubleInfo = nodeRoot.SelectSingleNode("//TroubleInfo")
        nodeTroubleInfo.InnerText = txtNotes.Text
        nodeDateTimeSaved = nodeRoot.SelectSingleNode("//DateTimeSaved")
        nodeDateTimeSaved.InnerText = strTime
        xmlData.Save(FileName)
        MsgBox("SAVE Button Pressed!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Note saved successfully!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error saving note. The error was: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error saving information to file.")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a file. It's part of the assembly. You cannot write to it.

The best you could do is read from the assembly and write to a separate XML file on disk. *That* file, you could read and write.

Comment: The issue I have is if I create a new XML file into the Program Files directory, I have to run my app with admin privileges. Where/what should I do with the xml files?

Comment: Write it to your program's Application Data folder. Notice how there's a `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio` folder? Create a `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\yourCompany\yourProduct` folder during installation.